# How to obtain private key from LetsEncrypt trough Heroku?

Tags: certificate, letsencrypt, heroku

I'm using Automated Certificate Management on Heroku through Letsencrypt.

We're moving our app to a different hosting environment and would like to move the certificate to this new server as well.

**Is it possible to extract the private key from Letsencrypt?**

If so, a pointer to documentation describing the process is highly appreciated.

Comment: What method are you currently using to upload the certificate to Heroku?

Comment: I m using automated certificate management from Heroku (which uses letsencrypt to provide the actual certificates). I'm guessing the private key lives somewhere on virtual machine (dyno in heroku terms) heroku provides.

Comment: Any specific reason that you need to extract _this_ certificate & key instead of obtaining a new one from LE?

Comment: We dont know the exact time our it department will make the DNS change for pointing the DN to the new hosting environment. We figured that if we already installed the certificate on the new environment, we would not have to schedule with IT department.

Comment: I suppose that also means you've ruled out LE's "DNS-based verification" mode to obtain a cert before actually switching over hosting?

Comment: Yeah its ruled out because that would require actions from IT as well. But we'll install s new certificate and accept some security warnings along the way.